# An android DiffUtils shortcoming

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I find that all the information about DiffUtil on the internet is about how to use DiffUtil. 
Is there any one who considers that using DiffUtil leads to large memory consuming?
If i have a list of 5000 objects(for example: post) in it, then i scroll RecyclerView and load 40 objects more. This means memory hold two lists(old list contains 5000 objects and new list contains 5040 objects) if using DiffUtil. So when loading data, the app consumes memory largely.
The way may solve this problem is that don't hold two lists. Showing as below:

```
DiffUtil.DiffResult recyclerViewDiff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return oldelist.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return oldlist.size() + increasedData.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                boolean isIncreaseDataPos = newItemPosition >= oldlist.size();
                newItemPosition = !isIncreaseDataPos ? newItemPosition : newItemPosition - oldlist.size();

                Object newItem = !isIncreaseDataPos ? oldlist.get(newItemPosition) : increaseData.get(newItemPosition);
                return oldlist.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newItem);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return ...;
            }
        });
```

But what if i change the item in list(not add more data)? Is there any way to use DiffUtil without holding two lists to update view except using notifyItemChanged(position) by myself?

Comment: but if you *know* exactly what has changed what do you need at all `DiffUtil` for?

Comment: So, what you mean is that we have `notifyItemChanged()`, `notifyItemInserted`,`notifyItemMoved` and so on, then we don't need `DiffUtil`? We use it just because it's convenient no because we don't know exactly what has changed.

Comment: `DiffUtil` simply finds what items were changed, inserted, moved and removed, if you already know that then you dont need `DiffUtil` at all - the docs say: *"DiffUtil is a utility class that can calculate the difference between two lists and output a list of update operations that converts the first list into the second one."*

Comment: So, We should not use ```DiffUtil``` if we know which item or item position has been changed because in that case, ```notifyItemChanged``` or ```notifyItemInserted``` or ```notifyItemMoved``` etc... are more appropriate and faster than ```DiffUtil```. We should use ```DiffUtil``` **only when we do not know which item or item position or range has been changed.**